# Concat a String in python

Tags: python-2.7, split, concatenation

this is are my files

```
2015125_0r89_PEO.txt 
2015125_0r89_PED.txt
2015125_0r89_PEN.txt

2015126_0r89_PEO.txt 
2015126_0r89_PED.txt
2015126_0r89_PEN.txt

2015127_0r89_PEO.txt 
2015127_0r89_PED.txt
2015127_0r89_PEN.txt
```

and I want to change to this:

```
US.CAR.PEO.D.2015.125.txt
US.CAR.PED.D.2015.125.txt
US.CAR.PEN.D.2015.125.txt

US.CAR.PEO.D.2015.126.txt
US.CAR.PED.D.2015.126.txt
US.CAR.PEN.D.2015.126.txt

US.CAR.PEO.D.2015.127.txt
US.CAR.PED.D.2015.127.txt
US.CAR.PEN.D.2015.127.txt
```

this is my code so far,

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\data\\MAX\\') #location files
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    a = path.split("_") 
    b = a[2].split(".") 
    c = "US.CAR."+ b[0] + ".D." + a[0]
    print c
```

when I run the script it's no make any error, but not change the name of the files *.txt* which it is what it should supposed to do

any help?

Comment: to remane a file you have to use `os.rename`

Comment: `US.CAR.PEO.D.C:\data\MAX\2015125
US.CAR.PED.D.C:\data\MAX\2015125
US.CAR.PEN.D.C:\data\MAX\2015125

US.CAR.PEO.D.C:\data\MAX\2015126
US.CAR.PED.D.C:\data\MAX\2015126
US.CAR.PEN.D.C:\data\MAX\2015126

US.CAR.PEO.D.2015.C:\data\MAX\2015127
US.CAR.PED.D.2015.C:\data\MAX\2015127
US.CAR.PEN.D.2015.C:\data\MAX\2015127`

Comment: @Copperfield like this? `for path in paths:
    a = path.split("_") 
    b = a[2].split(".") 
    c = "US.CAR."+ b[0] + ".D." + a[0]
    os.rename(path, c)`

Comment: @Armando Something like that. Also, learn to build long strings in Python using string formatting. Using JavaScript-style concatenation with plusses is usually by far more inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do it by first getting the path and then manipulating it will get bad results, in this case is best first get the name of the file, make the changes to it and then change the name of the file itself, like this

```
for root,_,filenames in os.walk('C:\\data\\MAX\\'):
    for name in filenames:
        print "original:", name
        a = name.split("_")
        b = a[2].split(".")
        new = "US.CAR.{}.D.{}.{}".format(b[0],a[0],b[1]) #don't forget the file extention 
        print "new",new
        os.rename( os.path.join(root,name), os.path.join(root,new) )
```

string concatenation is more inefficient, the best way is using string [formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).